# Can't install kernel headers for 5.13.0-37-generic

Tags: 20.04, kernel

I have 5.13.0-37-generic version of my kernel.

```
>uname -r
5.13.0-37-generic
```

I need to install headers for it, but when i am running

```
>apt search linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

It finds nothing.
The closest version of headers is

```
>sudo apt search  linux-headers
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
linux-headers-5.13.0-35-generic/now 5.13.0-35.40~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,local]
  Linux kernel headers for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

What should do I to fix this problem? I new to linux, so please explain how to fix it.

Update and upgrade.

```
Hit:1 http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-framework/apt lucid InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                          
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                  
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]                                                                                                                               
Hit:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x focal InRelease                                                                                    
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu focal InRelease                            
Hit:7 https://repo.pritunl.com/stable/apt focal InRelease                                                 
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu focal InRelease                               
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [970 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [718 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main Translation-en [506 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [494 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [98,4 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [163 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [15,8 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [29,5 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages [4 642 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages [8 628 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe Translation-en [5 124 kB]                                                                                                                          
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3 603 kB]                                                                                                                   
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [3 016 kB]                                                                                                                      
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [7 794 kB]                                                                                                                      
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [44,3 kB]                                                                                                                     
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [265 kB]                                                                                                                      
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted i386 Packages [8 112 B]                                                                                                                          
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 Packages [22,0 kB]                                                                                                                         
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted Translation-en [6 212 B]                                                                                                                         
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [392 B]                                                                                                                     
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse i386 Packages [74,7 kB]                                                                                                                          
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages [144 kB]                                                                                                                          
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse Translation-en [104 kB]                                                                                                                          
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [48,4 kB]                                                                                                                  
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse DEP-11 48x48 Icons [23,1 kB]                                                                                                                     
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [192 kB]                                                                                                                      
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [214 B]                                                                                                                     
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [9 136 B]                                                                                                                   
Fetched 37,0 MB in 10s (3 702 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

/etc/apt/sources.list content

```
> cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
```

Comment: Please add output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` command.

Comment: Added in question.

Comment: I added to the answer how to restore the list.

Comment: I edit question with new update and upgrade. But headers not appeared.

Comment: Cange "Subscribed to" to all or something like that. `main-updates`  is not there.

Comment: Oh it maybe work, it update something

Comment: It should work now.

Comment: Yeah it work, thank u very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current HWE kernel is `5.13.0-40`. You need to update you system first.

It looks like `main` updates repository is disabled. Restore the default `sources.list` by running:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Open "Software & Updates" application and enable all repositories that are on the first tab especially `main`.

Also at the Updates tab change it to "All".

Then run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

You'll get the current kernel. Reboot to run this kernel.
And then you'll be able to install headers by

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-5.13.0-40-generic
```

Comment: I updated system, but nothing changed.                                                                               `> sudo apt install linux-headers-5.13.0-40-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.13.0-40-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-5.13.0-40-generic'
`

Comment: It is weird, but run `sudo apt install linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04`

Comment: And what is your kernel now? Are you connected to internet?

Comment: Sorry, i dont see your messeges. My kernel: `> uname -a
Linux spile-HP-Laptop-15s-eq1xxx 5.13.0-37-generic #42~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 15 15:44:28 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Are you connected to internet? Did update and upgrade commands run without errors? @Inc.ace

Comment: Yes, there arent any errors. I'll update question with output.

Comment: linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 does not help too.

Comment: @Inc.ace See the updated answer.

Comment: This tips already was were. [Screen of my Software & Updates](https://dropmefiles.com/KtHEW)

Comment: It should work. The update command doesn't check `main`.

Comment: Please check the Updates tab. The "subscrebed to" field.

Comment: subscrebed to equal to custom

Comment: @Inc.ace I added info.

Comment: Yeah it work, thank u very much!